# Asp.net Core 2.1 MVC Decode in a View

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

Hi I'm trying to use a ternary operator in the razor view. However the view engine will encode special characters such as < and >.

Code:

```
@(item.Id == 0 ? "" :Html.Raw(System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode("<span class=\"card-text h5 text-danger\">")) + item.Name.ToString() + Html.Raw(System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode("</span>")))
```

Generated output:

```
&lt;span class=&quot;card-text h5 text-danger&quot;&gt;Hot Sandwiches&lt;/span&gt;
```

While my goal is:

> <span class="card-text h5 text-danger">Hot
>   Sandwiches</span>

I have tried several options, such as

```
Html.Raw(text)  
Html.Raw(System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(text))    
Html.Raw(System.Net.WebUtility.UrlDecode(text))
Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(text))
Html.Raw(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(text))
```

None of these worked.
Any advice is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Are you wanting to render the HTML as a string or HTML? Ex, `@{var span = "<span class='card-text h5 text-danger'>Hot Sandwiches</span>";}` display as string, use `@span`, result would be `<span class='card-text h5 text-danger'>Hot Sandwiches</span>` or `@Html.Raw(span)`, result would be `Hot Sandwiches`

Comment: That works! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@{
    var span = "<span class='card-text h5 text-danger'>Hot Sandwiches</span>";
}`

To display as string, use `@span`, result:

> `<span class='card-text h5 text-danger'>Hot Sandwiches</span>`

or `@Html.Raw(span)`, result:

> Hot Sandwiches